# How do i resolve \n for string concatenation in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have used "\n" for string concatenation in the python code but it doesn't working. "\n" is appending along with the context to the list data

```
data = []
context_data = [('What is the available storage capability', '124578'), ('what is the available budget set', '12587'), ('what is the available budget set', '12587')]
for part in context_data:
    s = "User : "+part[0]+" \nUlta : "+part[1]
    data.append(s)
print(data)
```

['User : What is the available storage capability \nUlta : 124578', 'User : what is the available budget set \nUlta : 12587', 'User : what is the available budget set \nUlta : 12587']

Comment: please explain what is exact issue is ? also details out what is expected output.

Comment: Replace `data = []` with `data = ''` and `data.append(s)` with `data += s`.

Comment: Alternatively, replace `print(data)` with `print(''.join(data))`.

Comment: BTW, don't you wanna put that `print` **outside** the `for` loop (i.e., after it)?

Comment: "\n" is printing along with output, how to solve this, by appending to a list

Answer (score 0):

It is not working as you are appending it to data... try it without data.

Code:

```
context_data = [('What is the available storage capability', '124578'), ('what is the available budget set', '12587'), ('what is the available budget set', '12587')]
for part in context_data:
    s = "User : "+part[0]+" \nUlta : "+part[1]
    print(s)
```

Output:

```
User : What is the available storage capability
Ulta : 124578
User : what is the available budget set 
Ulta : 12587
User : what is the available budget set 
Ulta : 12587
```

Comment: I don't think the code and output came out well in the above response... just remove the first link and fifth line from your code and print(s) directly

Comment: Instead of stating your post is not ok and trying to explain it, just read [how to format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and fix it. Also, while editing, below the text box you have a preview of how your post will look like to help see if it is ok or not